# Fragments become white when asynctask runs

Tags: android

i am working on an app which has 4 fragments and each has listview on it which is populated by the data from server using asynctask so while browsing through fragments the fragments become white and on screen rotation or minimizing and maximizing it becomes ok ,any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider reading this and reformatting your question
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your fragments go through their fragment lifecycle as you move to other tabs. Consider saving the fragments state using the onSaveInstanceState method and restore the fragments state and rerender the lists on onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: how do you call your Asynctask?

Comment: Please post your relevant code